# How to validate a release before deploying using Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a weird requirement where i want to validate the release which is being deployed. For example let's say the current version which is deployed to Production is 5.0.0.12 and the new version which will be deployed using ansible is 5.0.0.13. This is a positive case so should be fine and go through but what if someone deploys the older version by mistake let's say 5.0.0.05.

I want to validate this and prompts to the user like "You are deploying an older version from what we have in Production. Do you want to Continue?"

This is how the user will pass the release version from the cmd -

`./ansible-playbook my-main.yml --tags=repodownload,copyrepo,deploy -e my_release_version=5.0.0-05 -e target_env=prod`

And current release version can be fetch through symlink like below shows 5.0.0.12 is deployed at the moment -

`my-app-> /opt/tomcat/Release5.0.0-12/my-app/webapp/`

Is that possible to put some conditions?

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#version-comparison you might want to take a look into this.